# Prism and parallelogram

Tags: geometry

The base of the prism is a parallelogram whose sides are $a = 13\ cm$, $b = 14\ cm$ and diagonal $d = 15\ cm$. Calculate the volume of that prism if its area is $876\ cm^2$.

How to find the surface of a parallelogram, which is also the base of a prism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the area of a parallelogram where you are given the side lengths and the length of one diagonal, consider a triangle with those three sides. Such a triangle is exactly half of the parallelogram.

You can then use Heron's formula to calculate the area of the triangle, and double it to get the area of the parallelogram.